# Google-Now esque Mic Animation?

Tags: android, animation, mediarecorder, google-now

I'm in the process of creating a sound recording app, and would like to create an animation like the one in Google Now around my circular record button:

http://media.idownloadblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Google-Voice-Search-homepage-001.png

does anyone know how I could go about doing this??

Comment: Did you implemented this effect? I wanna do the same.

Answer (score 0):

That is a combination Scale and Alpha Animations.

As it scales up, background becomes more transparent.

You'll need to run these animation at the same time.

I suggest using ValueAnimator (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html).

For the Scale Animation, you should use OvershootInterpolator for the bouncing effect (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/OvershootInterpolator.html)